# How to write a reader of .map files from Delphi in C#?

Tags: c#, delphi, file-format, map-files

I am attempting to make a .map file reader in a different programming language (c#). This is because a friend of mine has a whole load of .map files he wants to use in Unity. Now, what (I think) happens is that the Delphi level editor stores the level as a series of symbols. The level editor then 'reads' this series of symbols, and constructs a map on them. So this series of symbols is a save file, I suppose.

Now, what I want to do is reconstruct this reader in c#. Therefore I have to find the relevant code, and what reads the symbols. However, I don't know the Delphi language - so I need to know how the symbol conversion works, and what each symbol is converted to. Any links/advice/answers are appreciated. I will post the source code if necessary, but it's quite long.

Comment: My advice would be to understand the Delphi code first, and then write equivalent C# code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please realize that you've given *no* details about the format of the file, and *no* details about how the program works. What kind of answer could you possibly have expected about how to read those files? You're right that you need to know how the symbol conversion works, so go do that. Although the code is in Delphi, that doesn't mean it's in Klingon. You should still be able to read the identifiers and understand function names. Study the code, and you will start to get an idea of how it works. Come back here when you have specific problems.

Comment: Isn't there any documentation on the structure of Unity .map files? It should not be too hard to find out how to read them in C# or any other language you know.